# Excel assume dates is in US format

Tags: date, excel, vba

I created  a macro that copy a column where 02/04/2013 12:35 means 2nd of April
I then paste it and use text to columns to get rid of the time part. Excel for some reason than interpret it as 4th of February. Tried both selecting text at the last step of the text to columns and date but in both cases it get flipped.

Dates that cannot be flipped like 28/03/2013 remains correct.

If I don't use a macro but manually do it Excel doesn't flip the day and month only when running it as a macro that occurs. Noticed it occurs in another macro as well when just copy a cell with a date to another cell with a date.

Comment: hmmm, what are your workstations regional settings set to?

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
Sub Convert_Dates()

Dim Rng As Range
Set Rng = Selection

For Each c In Rng
    c.Value = DateSerial(Right(Split(c)(0), 4), Mid(Split(c)(0), 4, 2), Left(Split(c)(0), 2))
Next c

End Sub
```

It can also help with "text dates" to use Format and "dd/mmm/yyyy" as this doesn't tend to get mixed up.